# Android: Switching between two activities Error - Unfortunately “App Name” has stopped

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm learning android app developing, then this problem came up and I'm not sure if people have this problem before but it says my app has stopped in the emulator. This is a basic currency converter.

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {
    private final int GET_SECACT_RES = 6;
    public TextView result;
    public EditText amount;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button myB = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        myB.setOnClickListener(this);
        amount =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
        result=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("amount", amount.getText().toString());
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, GET_SECACT_RES);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == GET_SECACT_RES){
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String txt = data.getStringExtra("result");
                result.setText(txt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public Double result;

    RadioButton usDollar = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.usDollar);
    RadioButton japaneseYen = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.japaneseYen);
    String amountAdded = getIntent().getStringExtra("amount");
    Double doubleAmount = Double.parseDouble(amountAdded);


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_activity);
        Button myB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        myB.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void calculate() {
        if(usDollar.isSelected()){
            result = 1.09 * doubleAmount;
        }
        if (japaneseYen.isSelected()) {
           result = 0.7 * doubleAmount;
        }
    }
    public void onClick(View v){
        calculate();
        Intent res = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        res.putExtra("result", result.toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK,res);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Logcat:

```
04-21 18:01:01.085 7559-7559/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-21 18:01:01.086 7559-7559/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
04-21 18:01:01.413 7559-7559/com.example.calculatorlab5 W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.calculatorlab5-2/lib/x86
04-21 18:01:01.516 7559-7559/com.example.calculatorlab5 I/InstantRun: Starting Instant Run Server for com.example.calculatorlab5


[ 04-21 18:01:01.566  7559: 7587 D/         ]

HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x9abc6300, tid 7587
04-21 18:01:01.573 7559-7587/com.example.calculatorlab5 I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-21 18:01:01.573 7559-7587/com.example.calculatorlab5 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
04-21 18:01:01.574 7559-7587/com.example.calculatorlab5 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
04-21 18:01:01.574 7559-7587/com.example.calculatorlab5 D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
```

Please help. Thank you very much for this.

Comment: post the Logcat too.

Comment: You cannot call `findViewById()` or `getIntent()` where you currently are in `SecondActivity`. Move those initializations to `onCreate()`, similar to what you have in `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error here:

```
  Double doubleAmount = Double.parseDouble("amountAdded");
```

Remove the quotes from amountAdded.

```
 Double doubleAmount = Double.parseDouble(amountAdded);
```